# intro slider without slide animation

Tags: react-native

Could you suggest a starting point or reference library to have a carousel/intro-slider where the effect is not of slide but of overriding. For example, if you check this [image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider/HEAD/Images/button-example.gif) it is quite close, but upon slide previous image slide left too. What I want is an overriding kind of impact such that only the new layer slides and covers the one if scrolled over 50% else slides back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **[react-native-viewpager](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-viewpager)** for you.

**Installing**

```
yarn add @react-native-community/viewpager
```

**Usage**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager';

const MyPager = () => {
  return (
    <ViewPager style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0}>
      <View key="1">
        <Text>First page</Text>
      </View>
      <View key="2">
        <Text>Second page</Text>
      </View>
    </ViewPager>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewPager: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: Based on example, I see the old slides getting slided/pushed left by new slide instead of overlapping. Are you sure it provides the functionality of transition without sliding previous layer?